# "File Not Found" error when attempting to add user to Farm Administrators group in SharePoint 2019 Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

My company has a SharePoint 2019 on premise environment. Our farm administrator left our company recently and I have been asked to take over administration of our SharePoint environment. The first thing I need to do is add myself to the Farm Administrators group. I can launch Central Administration and get to the People and Groups : Farm Administrators page, but when I click the "New" link to add a user, I get error "Sorry, something went wrong. File Not Found."

[image]

I have access to the diagnostic logs, but I am not able to find the source of the "File Not Found" error. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your account has been added to AD and it is not disabled. Then run Central Administration as administrator, add
   yourself to the Farm Administrators group.
2. try to add yourself to SharePoint farm administrators by using below PowerShell instead of from UI

code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#User to Add 
$UserID="domain\userID"

#Get Central Admin Web App 
$CAWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"}

#Get Central Admin site 
$CAWeb = Get-SPweb($CAWebApp.Url)
#Get Farm Administrators Group 
$FarmAdminGroup = $CAWeb.SiteGroups["Farm Administrators"]
#Add user to the Group 
$FarmAdminGroup.AddUser($UserID,"",$UserID , "") 
Write-Host "User: $($UserID) has been added to Farm Administrators Group!" 
$CAWeb.Dispose()
```

If the issue insists, please search Correlation Id in your ULS logs and post the related logs here. I will check for you.

Comment: Is there any new progress , and if you have extra questions about my answer, please click "Comment".